# No route matched for event dispatch error request

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I'd like to setup my error redirection inside my application module bootstrap.

Here is my code that attaches the `handleError function` to the event manager:

```
$em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this,'handleError'));
```

Here is the `handleError` method inside the `Application\Module` class.

```
public function handleError(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // error here is error-router-no-match
    // echo $e->getError();
}
```

From this code, I want to add a clause that performs a redirect to the route `application.index.error` (`Application\Controller\IndexController`,`errorAction`)

the problem im facing is there is no way of telling when the request is from the error handle redirection, so an infinite loop occurs.

Also,

this fails because there is no match at the moment:

```
 $router = $sm->get('router');
 $request = $sm->get('request');
 $matchedRoute = $router->match($request);
 $params = $matchedRoute->getParams();
```

How do I determine inside the `handleError` method that the request is actually from the error handler request when **no route is matched** and if i need to modify the `router` to ensure a route match is found.

Comment: can't you pass a parameter when it is an error? like `error=1` or whatever? Just a thought

Comment: Id prefer to do it a more proper way if there is one

Comment: Well I wouldn't say that isn't proper since you know who is throwing the error.

Comment: I agree. But Im wondering if there is an official zend way of doing this, but if not i probably will end up using your method.

Comment: Hmm understand. Don't know if there is... let's wait to see if someone can help...

Comment: With no route match how would i be able to access the error property anyways unless its right from the $_REQUEST superglobals, but im not using that. UNLESS i can access from request object regardless of a route match

Comment: Instead of passing an error variable as suggested by @Jorge Campos, you could store a variable in a session container.  Then just have your `handleError()` method check for this. Just a thought.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but surely an infinite loop would indicate that the route you're attempting to redirect to also does not exist (for it to trigger the handler after redirect)? In which case the fix would be to make sure the route you're redirecting to actually does exist before redirecting to it. Like I said, maybe I'm missing something here :o/